# How to Change Vertex List in a Grid Graph

Tags: functions, graphs-and-networks

I would like to actually change the vertices in a grid graph instead of simply changing the label. Ultimately, I want the vertices to be points on a plane.

So if given a simple grid graph

```
g = GridGraph[{2,2},VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

How can I change the vertex 1 to be `{0,0}`, 2 to be `{0,1}`, 3 to be `{1,0}`, and 4 to be `{1,1}`, so that

```
VertexList[g] = {{0,0},{0,1},{1,0},{1,1}}?
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cand use VertexReplace to replace each vertex with its coordinates or any other values.

```
g = GridGraph[{2, 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
VertexReplace[g, Thread[VertexList[g] -> GraphEmbedding[g]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[vReplace]
vReplace  = VertexReplace[g, v_ :> Floor @ GraphEmbedding[g][[v]] - 1]  (* or *)
vReplace =  VertexReplace[#, v_ :> 
  QuotientRemainder[v - 1, First["Dimension" /. Last[GraphLayout /. Options[#]]]]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
{r, c} = {2, 2};
g = GridGraph[{r, c}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{g, vReplace @ g}]
```

[image]

With `{r, c} = {3, 5}` we get

[image]

And with `{r, c} = {5, 3}` we get

[image]

**Update:** Building the grid graph from scratch:

```
gridGraph[{r_, c_}, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{v = QuotientRemainder[# - 1, r] & /@ Range[r c], e}, 
  e = If[ManhattanDistance @@ # == 1, UndirectedEdge @@ #, ## &[]] & /@ Subsets[v, {2}];
  Graph[v, v, VertexCoordinates -> Thread[v-> v], o]]
```

**Example:**

```
gridGraph[{5, 6}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 25, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Graph[{
  Labeled[1, "{0,0}"], 
  Labeled[2, "{0,1}"], 
  Labeled[3, "{1,0}"], 
  Labeled[4, "{1,1}"]}, 
  {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 2 <-> 4},
 VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**  Use [`NearestNeighborGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph.html) with exact coordinates.

```
gridGraph[dims_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 NearestNeighborGraph[Tuples[Range /@ dims], opt]

gridGraph[{3, 2}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

---

**Old answer:**

Assuming that you don't just want to change the label that is displayed, but actually change the vertex name, you can do this:

Look at in which order `GridGraph` numbers vertices, generate the corresponding desired names with `Tuple`, and finally replace the integers with the desired names.

```
In[]:= g = GridGraph[{2, 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

In[]:= names = Tuples[{Range[3], Range[2]}]
Out[]= {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}}

In[]:= rules = Thread[Range@Length[names] -> names]
Out[]= {1 -> {1, 1}, 2 -> {1, 2}, 3 -> {2, 1}, 4 -> {2, 2}, 5 -> {3, 1}, 6 -> {3, 2}}

In[]:= Graph[
 VertexList[g] /. rules, EdgeList[g] /. rules,
 VertexLabels -> "Name"
 ]
```